# Is it possible to send email with display name and email id in nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, node-modules, nodemailer

My requirement is I want to send an email to a user on her/his email address but also want to send their display-name of user is it possible with nodemailer or any other alternative?

```
const mailOptions = {
            from : "dev@test.com",
            to : ["mymail@gmail.com"],
            
            subject : "Test",
            text: "New test"
        };
```

this configurations sent a to mymail@gmail.com and in from section of mail displaying dev@test.com  but I want to display from name like **Development Server** as well with the from mail, how can i archive this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to send email with user name and other data.

```
const name ='abc',email='abc@yopmail.com',phone='1234',message='hello there'
const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.AUTH_EMAIL,
    to: "mymail@gmail.com",
    subject: 'Community Partnership Project Contact Form Inquiry',
    html: `<div><p>Name: ${name}</p><br/><p>Email: ${email}</p><br/><p>Phone: ${phone}</p><br/><p>Message: ${message}</p></div>`
}
```

Comment: Hey, @vipul, I know we can pass this in HTML but I wanted it it the "from" section of the mail for example in outlook mail is displaying from section From : "dev@test.com" but i want to display From : Development Server, Hope you got it

Comment: Ok so you want Name of organization in from section like you received mail from ABC right ?